# Best Practice to display local markers and a wider area of points of interest markers?

Tags: leaflet

I've created a base layer and 6 different overlay (Points of Interest) layers for a leaflet map.

The base layer of markers can appear on the map almost anywhere in the world, but I want the POI layers to appear only if they are in the same area (mapBounds) of the base layer. Probably the screen size.

All the data is pulled from a MySQL database and using Ajax I create the various sets of markers from two different tables, base and poi. This much is all done and working, you can see it at https://net-control.us/map2.php. The green and blue markers are from the base table, other markers are currently selected for view by clicking on the appropriate icon in the lower right. The only one active at the moment is 'Fire Station'. But if you zoom out far enough you will see additional fire stations in the Kansas City area, and in Florida. Those sets are not needed.

After the query runs I create a fitBounds variable of the base layer and another poiBounds for the poi layer. But I'm not sure I need the poiBounds. The number of base markers is generally less than 50 for the base query, but if all the poi markers are pulled world wide that number could be very large.

So I'm hoping someone can help me determine a best practice for this kind of scenario and maybe offer up an example of how it should be done. Should I...
1) Download all POIs and not worry about them appearing outside the base bounds layer? Should I inhibit them from showing in the javascript or in the SQL? How?
2) If I inhibit the unwanted points from SQL do I test one POI at a time to see if its included in the base bounds? How? Are there MySQL functions perhaps to work with this kind of data?

I'm fairly new at leaflet maps and would appreciate examples if appropriate.

Comment: At first glance, it sounds like you should use the `LIMIT` keyword in your SQL queries.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Not a bad idea but I don't have any real way to keep track of the rows that the POI values would occupy let alone how many there might be. The end user can add POI's for future use and well.. you know MySQL there is no way of telling where that new entry would end up.

Comment: Suppose map.getBounds() returns; Var bbox = map.getBounds();

_northEast: {lat: 34.56312121279482, lng: -83.29627990722658,  …}
_southWest: {lat: 34.07143110146333, lng: -84.2926025390625,  …} How do I test a POI lat/lng point to be sure its inside?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html

Comment: @IvanSanchez I appreciate that but I think its written in latin because its way over my head. Do I define the latitude column and the longitude column have a spacial index? Or is it a combination of the two, or maybe I should only have one column that contains both lat and lng? when I run; ALTER TABLE `ncm`.`poi` ADD SPATIAL `g` (`latitude`) I get an error: The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2) If I inhibit the unwanted points from SQL do I test one POI at a time to see if its included in the base bounds? How? Are there MySQL functions perhaps to work with this kind of data?

You probably want a column of type `POINT`, a spatial index on such column (which internally is likely to be implemented as an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)), and [spatial relation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrcontains) on your SQL query to make use of that index.

Start by reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html. **Take your time**, as spatial databases, spatial data types and spatial indices work a bit differently than their non-spatial equivalents.

Comment: I like your optimism in thinking I can learn this stuff, I only wish I shared it. But it most likely is the solution.